# Publish successful, not able to trigger in Azure Synapse Analytics

Tags: azure, continuous-integration, azure-synapse-pipeline

I have a set of Notebooks and pipelines in Azure Synapse pipelines, which are working when I debug. Publish is also successful, but when I trigger the pipelines, it says that "Pipeline is not found, please publish first" as in below screenshot!

[image]

When I use `Trigger Now` option, it shows below image!

[image]

I disconnected Git at backend, and reconfigured the new branch, but unfortunately the same issue again. I am publishing from my collaboration branch. All my Notebooks and pipelines are in collaboration branch!

Can someone, please help me what is wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is normally an issue to be handled by the support team, but my idea is  changes to the master branch are not being published correctly, as I have seen a similar case before.

your synapse pipelines (which is in essence ADF) was working with old metadata/code and never updating as it should, hence why it worked in debug mode (current/new metadata) but not with triggers (published metadata/code). This seems to be a rare kind of issue or bug.

Try recreating the linked services and connection then replace it in the datasets. Recreating the resources (linked service etc) should fix it.